# How does matplotlib deal with overplotting in time series?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting a huge timeseries, having > 1M (10^6) datapoints.

I am plotting it using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(timeseries)
```

Since my screen resolution is <2k px, some overplotting is clearly taking place.
How does matplotlib deal with number of points >> screen resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Using the QT backend you can check point by point of the time series. Matplotlib doesn`t make any sampling to represent signals, based on what I know about the lib.

In the case of standard images formats (JPG or PNG), the representation is based on the DPI used to save the figure. PDF and SVG formats can be used to represent the signal in a vector format.

To use the QT backend and check your signal, if is everything ok, you can type this in the beginning of the script:

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('qtagg')
```

The tool offers zoom and drag tools to investigate a section of the signal.

[QT agg visualization tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epgcG.png)

Another good tool for data analysis is bokeh, which offers several options for interactive and HTML plots for web or research.